# Showing 1 row a person with several options

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic, pivot

The issue I'm facing is that I'm looking for a way to accomplish the following:

I need to get 1 row for each person with columns that show which groups have been linked to the person. I got the following 3 tables

1. Persons - Contains person data
2. Groups - Contains group data
3. Link - Contains the link between a person and groups

**Example data (script):**

```
Create table persons (uniqueid int, email varchar(50))
Create table groups (uniqueid int, title varchar(50))
Create table link (uniqueid int, groupid int, personid int)

insert into persons (uniqueid, email) values (1, 'firstname1.lastname1@domain.com'), (2, 'firstname2.lastname2@domain.com'), (3, 'firstname3.lastname3@domain.com')
insert into groups (uniqueid, title) values (1, 'Servicedesk'), (2, 'SecondLine'), (3, 'ThirdLine')
insert into link (uniqueid, groupid, personid) values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (4, 2, 1), (5, 3, 2), (6, 1, 3)
```

**Current query:**

```
select p.email, g.title
FROM link as l
    left join groups g on l.groupid = g.uniqueid
    left join persons p on l.personid = p.uniqueid
group by p.email, g.title
```

**Output current query:**

```
email                           title
firstname1.lastname1@domain.com SecondLine
firstname1.lastname1@domain.com Servicedesk
firstname2.lastname2@domain.com Servicedesk
firstname2.lastname2@domain.com ThirdLine
firstname3.lastname3@domain.com Servicedesk
```

**Expected end result:**

```
email                           Group1       Group2       Group3       
firstname1.lastname1@domain.com Servicedesk  SecondLine   NULL
firstname2.lastname2@domain.com Servicedesk  NULL         NULL
firstname3.lastname3@domain.com Servicedesk  NULL         NULL
```

To start trying to solve this I have tried to create 1 row per person with all groups in 1 column by using `FOR XML PATH ('')` but this generates error `Column name 'Email Address' contains an invalid XML identifier as required by FOR XML; ' '(0x0020) is the first character at fault.` on my production environment.
After this row I wanted to split them to the columns.
At the moment I'm in search of the correct functions to use so I can build the full query.

Comment: I'm confused as to how to get to your expected result, where is group2 and group3 derived?

Comment: I've got a function that splits the string into multiple columns ready. But I can't get my data into 1 row per emailadres yet. So I got nothing to split yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate the column's names on the fly and use this in `PIVOT`

```
DECLARE @persons TABLE (uniqueid int, email varchar(50))
DECLARE @groups TABLE(uniqueid int, title varchar(50))
DECLARE @link TABLE(uniqueid int, groupid int, personid int)

insert into @persons (uniqueid, email) values (1, 'firstname1.lastname1@domain.com'), (2, 'firstname2.lastname2@domain.com'), (3, 'firstname3.lastname3@domain.com')
insert into @groups (uniqueid, title) values (1, 'Servicedesk'), (2, 'SecondLine'), (3, 'ThirdLine')
insert into @link (uniqueid, groupid, personid) values (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (4, 2, 1), (5, 3, 2), (6, 1, 3)

SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    select p.email
          ,g.title
          ,'Group'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p.email ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(2)) AS ColumnName
    FROM @link as l
        left join @groups g on l.groupid = g.uniqueid
        left join @persons p on l.personid = p.uniqueid
    group by p.email, g.title
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(title) FOR ColumnName IN(Group1,Group2,Group3, Group4 /*add as many as you need*/)
) AS p;
```

The result

```
email                           Group1      Group2      Group3  Group4
firstname1.lastname1@domain.com SecondLine  Servicedesk NULL    NULL
firstname2.lastname2@domain.com Servicedesk ThirdLine   NULL    NULL
firstname3.lastname3@domain.com Servicedesk NULL        NULL    NULL
```

Comment: great answer, also adding the functionality to add more groups to help future proof OPs code +1

Comment: This way of dynamic Pivotting was exactly what I was looking for. +1